# MSBuild SqlPublishTask not running pre-deploy script?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a `SQL Server Database Project` in Visual Studio 2015. This project is being used by the CI/CD tool to publish to the target databases using `msbuild` with a `SqlPublishTask` and an associated publish profile.

The `msbuild` command looks something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "c:\pathto\MySqlProj\MySql.sqlproj" /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="c:\pathto\MySqlProj\MyProfile.publish.xml" /p:UpdateDatabase=True /p:PublishScriptFileName="MySqlProj.ssdt-artefact.sql" /m /nr:false
```

Any schema related changes are successfully published.

However, the pre-build sql script is not run. I can see this because old data that should be removed by the pre-build script is not. I have also tested the pre-build script separately and it works fine.

I have checked and the pre-build script has a `Build Action` of `PreDeploy`. The location of the pre-build script in the project is:

```
c:\pathto\MySqlProj\Scripts\Pre-Deploy\Script.PreDeployment.sql
```

Any idea why the pre-deploy script is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this. From experimentation it looks like even though a pre-deployment script is created using the `Pre-Deployment Script` template this doesn't mark the file as being a pre-deployment script.

Instead, it appears that MSBuild is looking for a specific comment section at the start of the file in order to determine if it is a pre-deployment script:

```
/*
 Pre-Deployment Script Template                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This file contains SQL statements that will be executed before the build script.   
 Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the pre-deployment script.          
 Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
 Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the pre-deployment script.        
 Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                            
               SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

In my case, those comments had been removed. Adding them back resulted in the script being run. The same is true for post-deployment scripts.